# Given a zod schema with a discriminated union, how might one refine the form to a discriminated type?

Tags: typescript, react-hook-form, zod

Given a schema that is a discriminated union, I'd like to be able to narrow the type of the form based on the discriminant. However, attempting to type guard with `watch` or `getValues` does not work.

Is it possible to refine the type of `form` to be of a more specific sub-type?

```js
const BazSchema = z.object({
  type: z.literal('baz'),
  baz: z.string(),
});
type BazSchema = z.infer<typeof BazSchema>;
const BarSchema = z.object({
  type: z.literal('bar'),
  bar: z.string(),
});
type BarSchema = z.infer<typeof BarSchema>;

const Schema = z.discriminatedUnion('type', [BazSchema, BarSchema]);

type Schema = z.infer<typeof Schema>;

export function MyComponent() {
  const form = useForm<Schema>({
    defaultValues: {
      type: 'baz',
    },
  });

  const type = form.watch('type');
  if (type === 'baz') {
    return <BazForm form={form} />;
  }
}

export function BazForm({ form }: { form: UseFormReturn<BazSchema> }) {
  return (
    <form {...form}>
      <input {...form.register('baz')} />
    </form>
  );

}
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/zod-discriminated-union-mpxn4h?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx